# Is there a way of passing date input value of a django form to a filter queryset

Tags: django-models, django-forms

I am trying to filter a queryset based on input date value from a form but I am not certain on how to access the "date" value.

Forms.py;

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'
```

Models.py :

```
class Milk(models.Model):
    milking_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Queryset generating function trial in admin.py class, nothing works.

```
...
def milk_record_per_day(self, request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = forms.DateInputForm(request.POST)
            slct_date = form.date
            data = (models.Milk.objects.filter(milking_date__date=slct_date)
                    .annotate(date=functions.TruncDate("milking_date"))
                    .values("date")
...
```

I expect to return a list of milk objects based on date input from the form, So far I get this error on POST request

```
'DateInput' object has no attribute 'date'
```

Comment: `DateInputForm` is not a form but a widget...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making things too complicated. You can create a form with this:

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class DateInputForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput)
```

and then process this in the view:

```
def milk_record_per_day(self, request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = forms.DateInputForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = models.Milk.objects.filter(milking_date__date=form.cleaned_data['date'])
            # ...
```

Comment: I have noted that upon querying a range of date for example data in between months by use of "__month__range" syntax then it throws an error : local variable 'data' referenced before assignment.

Comment: @PeterEvance: likely this has not (much) to do with it, but that you somehow use `data` before it was defined, for example because the `if` condition failed.

Comment: Please check this out for more clarity , here's my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363048/is-there-a-way-of-passing-date-input-value-of-a-django-form-to-a-filter-queryset